# Read more than 1 line csv file in C

Tags: c, csv

i am trying to read more than 1 line csv file,i've been sucessful to read 1 line csv file,can some one give me and example to read more than 1 line csv file?
here's the input sample :

```
Nama,Gaji,Zakat,Gaji Bersih
Ali,1234567,,
Sofyan,2345678,,
Kholimi,3456789,,
```

here's my 1 line csv read source code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char nama[100], gaji[100], zakat[100], bersih[100];

    FILE* f = fopen("2.csv", "r");

    fscanf(f, "%s %s %s %s", nama, gaji, zakat, bersih);

    //delete comma
    size_t len = strlen(gaji);
    size_t len1 = strlen(nama);
    size_t len2 = strlen(zakat);

    gaji[len - 1] = '\0';
    nama[len1 - 1] = '\0';
    zakat[len2 - 1] = '\0';
    //delete comma

    printf("%s \t %s \t %s \t %s \n", nama, gaji, zakat, bersih);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use the `fscanf` function in a loop like `while(!EOF)`.

Comment: can you please give me an example or reference link?

Comment: @NeiosFlameStuxnet Just google it, there are many examples around.

Comment: Something like `while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, f)) { /* process the input line */ }` is typically used.

Comment: Please show a short (3 line) sample input file in the question. You say "it works" but you are not dealing with the commas in a "Comma Separated Value" file.

Comment: @WeatherVane
Nama,Gaji,Zakat,Gaji Bersih <br/>
Ali,1234567,, <br/>
Sofyan,2345678,, <br/>
Kholimi,3456789,, <br/>

Comment: Read more than one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to read multiple lines with `fscanf` because they have the same
format, I'd read the whole line with `fgets` and parse it with `sscanf`, it
easier to deal with format errors this way:

```
int main(void)
{
    char nama[100], gaji[100], zakat[100], bersih[100];

    FILE* f = fopen("2.csv", "r");

    if(f == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char line[1024];
    size_t lineno = 0;
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
    {
        lineno++;
        if(sscanf(line, "%99s,%99s,%99s,%99s", nama, gaji, zakat, bersih) != 4)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "format error on line %zu\n", lineno);
            continue;
        }

        printf("line %zu: name: %s, gaji: %s, zakat: %s, bersih: %s\n", lineno, nama, gaji, zakat, bersih);
    }

    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

You could also use `strtok` to parse the lines of the CSV, for example when you
don't know how many columns there are or the columns have multiple empty spaces,
etc:

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE* f = fopen("2.csv", "r");

    if(f == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char line[1024];
    size_t lineno = 0;
    const char *delim = ",\n";
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
    {
        lineno++;

        char *token = strtok(line, delim);
        if(token == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "format error on line %zu\n", lineno);
            continue;
        }

        printf("line %zu:");

        do {
            printf("-%s- ", token);
        } while((token = strtok(NULL, delim)));

        putchar('\n');
    }

    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

For a line `"a,b,c,d,e"` it would print `"line 1: -a- -b- -c- -d- "`.

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly reading the CSV, even regardless of the only-one-line issue.

CSV is a format in which fields are separated by commas (not spaces, like your code assumes), and records are separated by newline characters; but it's actually much more complicated than that: There are escapes, and you can have commas and/or newlines within a single datum. The format is officially documented in [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180).

But you obviously shouldn't have to reinvent the wheel and write your own CSV parsing code. Instead, use one of the publicly-available CSV parser libraries, such as [semitrivial's csv_parser](https://github.com/semitrivial/csv_parser) or the venerable [libcsv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libcsv/files/).

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char nama[100], gaji[100], zakat[100], bersih[100];

    FILE* f = fopen("2.csv", "r");

    while(fscanf(f, "%s %s %s %s", nama, gaji, zakat, bersih)!=EOF){

        //delete comma
        size_t len = strlen(gaji);
        size_t len1 = strlen(nama);
        size_t len2 = strlen(zakat);

        gaji[len - 1] = '\0';
        nama[len1 - 1] = '\0';
        zakat[len2 - 1] = '\0';
        //delete comma

        printf("%s \t %s \t %s \t %s \n", nama, gaji, zakat, bersih);
    }

    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

do you want to end up with something like this?

Comment: How does this deal with the commas in a CSV file?

Comment: @WeatherVane quote from question: _i am trying to read more than 1 line csv file,i've been sucessful to read 1 line csv file,can some one give me and example to read more than 1 line csv file?

here's my 1 line csv read source code :_, I copied his code and adjusted so it reads more than 1 line, he says that this code works for him but reads just one line, so I made it read multiple lines

Comment: I would also prefer `while(fscanf(f, "%s %s %s %s", nama, gaji, zakat, bersih) == 4)`

Comment: This one will fail for entries with spaces e.g.

Comment: That deals only with commas assuming that the are no spaces between the commas and the values. Also you might end up in an endless loop if one line has a wrong format.

Comment: This one will fail for entries with spaces e.g.

Comment: @Pablo ... assuming there *are* spaces as well as commas, since they are detected but the commas are not, which be read as part of the data.